# How to count number of element it cross while using find jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Supppose HTML structure is:

```
 <div class="history">
      <div id="10"></div>
      <div id="20"></div>
      <div id="30"></div>
      <div id="40"></div>
      <div id="50"></div>
 </div>
```

If this is HTML structure then in jquery:

```
 $(".history").find("#40").show();
```

If I use this then jquery has to loop over child element to find id with `#40`. It have to cross 3 element that is  `#10, #20, #30`. How to return the number of element is has to loop to find specific id.

Comment: You seem confused as to how selectors work. If you want to find the previous sibling elements, use `$(".history").find("#40").prevAll()`.

Comment: I don't know how it work. Can I have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**, since index is starting with `0` you will it's index will be the count of previous elements.

```js
alert($('#40').index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="history">
  <div id="10"></div>
  <div id="20"></div>
  <div id="30"></div>
  <div id="40"></div>
  <div id="50"></div>
</div>
```

or

```js
alert($('.history > div').index($('#40')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="history">
  <div id="10"></div>
  <div id="20"></div>
  <div id="30"></div>
  <div id="40"></div>
  <div id="50"></div>
</div>
```

or

```js
alert($('.history').children().index($('#40')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="history">
  <div id="10"></div>
  <div id="20"></div>
  <div id="30"></div>
  <div id="40"></div>
  <div id="50"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user254153 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite how selectors work. You can, however, still get the number of preceding elements quite easily. Since the element has an ID and IDs have to be unique, you can address it directly, there's no need to address the parent at all.

```js
alert($('#40').prevAll().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="history">
  <div id="10"></div>
  <div id="20"></div>
  <div id="30"></div>
  <div id="40"></div>
  <div id="50"></div>
</div>
```